# Item value is not showing up correctly in form

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a simple form on a report created by the wizard and in the form, the data is loaded with a fetch row process. 
After the fetch row process I have another process (type:pl/sql code) that should overwrite the value of some items under a certain condition.

The problem is, that the values of the items in the form are not updated through the plsql process, only in the session state the values are updated.

That seems strange to me. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a post calculation computation on the item.

Comment: This works thanks! Any idea why the page process does not work?

Comment: You could turn on debugging and see when your plsql process is being called vs. the post calc comp.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a **dynamic action** instead of a process. Its action should be "Set value".

Comment: This also works! Downside for me is that values have to be fetched from the database when the page has already loaded.